# Does sqrt(float) have a standard return type?

Tags: c++, sqrt, cmath, c-standard-library

I noticed that appleclang++ (v14.0.0) seems to return a single precision float when passing a float input to `cmath`'s `sqrt`. I was surprised to get different results when switching to gcc/clang.

Here's my minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  float f = 1+1e-7;
  auto X = sqrt(f);
  printf("%16s says X is a %6s with value: %0.17g\n",
#ifdef __clang__
#if defined(__apple_build_version__)
    "appleclang++",
#else
    "clang++",
#endif
#elif __GNUC__
    "g++",
#else
    "unknown compiler",
#endif
    std::is_same<float, decltype(X)>::value ? "float" : "double",
    X);
}
```

For different compilers I see:

```
    appleclang++ says X is a  float with value: 1
         clang++ says X is a double with value: 1.000000059604643
             g++ says X is a double with value: 1.000000059604643
```

I'm compiling with `-std=c++11` just [to be sure](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/).

If I switch to `std::sqrt` then everyone agrees it's a float, but I'm still curious. Is this behavior of `sqrt` indeed left up to the compiler or is appleclang being non-standard?

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the kind suggestion. Your link refers to `std::sqrt` which I've mentioned doesn't show this discrepancy. I belive https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/  is used in this case and my question is about different behaviors on different compilers.

Comment: The links I posted clearly describe what the C function `sqrt` and the C++ function `std::sqrt` do. What more do you need?  (side note: avoid cplusplus.com - it's full of incorrect information and bad examples). If the compilers you use implement the standard correctly, then the information I linked to should answer your question - they should all implement the behaviour described.

Comment: Btw; Yes, the code you posted is calling the C function.

Comment: OK. I can't tell from that page whether the standard let's it be ambiguous (I have compilers giving different answers). Would it help to rephrase my question as "how can I tell whether appleclang is following the standard definition of sqrt(float)?"

Comment: If you want to check what the standard says, you can go (for example) [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/).

Comment: *how can I tell whether appleclang is following the standard definition of sqrt(float)?*  Which standard?  C++11 doesn't define `sqrt` in the global namespace for the header files you've used (so your code depends on incidental declaration / global namespace pollution).  Ditto with `printf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, for most math functions, the C++ standard library has one overload for each floating point type that takes that type as parameter and also returns the same type. In addition there are overloads so that an integer argument will behave as if it was converted to `double` before being passed.

However, the problem here is that you use `sqrt` from the global namespace scope, which is wrong. It should be `std::sqrt`.

When including `<cmath>` you are only guaranteed that all overloads of `std::sqrt` are provided in the `std::` namespace scope. You need to include `<math.h>` to guarantee that all overloads are available in the global namespace scope and you need to include both to assure that all overloads are available in both the global and `std::` namespace scope. This affects all standard library headers derived from C btw.

I would however advice against using (solely) the `<math.h>` header as it lacks some other C++-specific math functions and also because it had been deprecated since C++98 and up until including C++20 before being de-deprecated for C++23. Similarly other `<_.h>` standard library headers had also been deprecated and lack certain parts that are included in their corresponding `<c_>` header. Unfortunately global namespace pollution can however not be avoided even when only including `<c_>` headers.

When mismatching the include, it is unspecified which overloads (if any) will be visible and then it is possible that instead of getting the `float sqrt(float)` overload you only get the `double sqrt(double)` overload, or any other one for that matter, e.g. one that expects an `int` and returns a `double`, which would cause very weird results.

(Although that last example is a bit far fetched, because there is no good implementation reason that would result in this behavior. The implementation reason for the `double` overload being special is that it is supplied by the underlying C standard library implementation, typically part of the system, rather than the C++ standard library implementation which is typically built separately on top of it.)

It is also possible that no overload will be visible and the program won't compile.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!  Indeed, switching `cmath` to `math.h` → everyone agrees X is float. (I'm content using std::sqrt, but wanted to understand the issue regardless)

Comment: Is there a clang, or gcc option to warn about this?

Comment: @alfC Off the top of my head, no. Maybe there is a warning flag for use of the `<_.h>` headers, because they have been deprecated until not so long ago. But that would not prevent misuse of the global scope names.

Comment: @alfC You can always try `clang++ -Weverything` and see if something pops up :) Also, `clang-tidy` may very well have a check/warning for this.

Comment: @alfC Clang's `-Wdouble-promotion` warns for the float->double mismatch, but I do not think that this is a warning one wants for all cases of float->double promotion. Clang-tidy has the check [performance-type-promotion-in-math-fn](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/performance/type-promotion-in-math-fn.html) which recognizes the float->double case as well and seems to be specific to the math functions. (However, the explanation on the linked page is incorrect. `::sin(0.f)` will call the float overload if <math.h> is included.)

Comment: I do wonder, for an implementation in which `<cmath>` declares both C's `sqrt()` in the global namespace and C++'s `std::sqrt()` what the impact of `using namespace std` will be on the usage `sqrt(a_double_value)`  (e.g. `sqrt(1.0)`).     I'm speculating the result is ambiguity.

Comment: @Peter No, the implementation must assure that this doesn't happen. It needs to use a using-declaration to import the name into `std` if it also wants to declare it in the global namespace scope, so that there aren't two distinct entities. (And that's probably what most C++ implementations do for the `double` overload at least.)